# Node.js connector documentation: Collection.remove

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to understand what does mean:

> w, {Number/String, > -1 || ‘majority’ || tag name} the write concern
>   for the operation where < 1 is no acknowlegement of write and w >=
>   1, w = ‘majority’ or tag acknowledges the write

At http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html?highlight=index#remove

I basically just don't understand at all what does that means. I understand the other explained options but not the "w" thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [**Write concern reference**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/)

Quote:

> 1:
>   Provides acknowledgment of write operations on a standalone mongod or the primary in a replica set.